# Bios Error on reboot Insuficient PCI Ressources xeon phi , supermicro-server

Tags: bios, pci, xeon-phi

I currently have a problem with an supermicro-server with an intel xeon phi installed. Its an old server, but when I am logging in and checking for the xeon phi it is still recognized. When I am trying to reboot the system there is a "Bios Popup Message" which is telling me "ERROR: Insuficient PCI Resources Detected!" that something is not right with my PCI-Ressources and that I should take out some of the PCI-E cards. But there is only one card, which seems to work. So I can just click "ignore" and the system is booting normally. But it is still a problem, because if I am trying to reboot it remotely, it is stucked on this error message.

Does someone know how to resolve this?

thanks in advance.

Most sincerely

Twinhand

Comment: What did vendor support say about this?

Comment: http://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=15556 Please change your BIOS settings:
BIOS > Advanced > PCIe/PCI/PnP Configuration > Above 4G Decoding and set it to Enabled. But that should be enabled

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure if you fixed this or not, but I just had the same issue. I was able to resolve it by doing what you said in your comment, I additionally changed:

- Changed MMIO High Size to 1024 GB
- MMIOHbase was set to 56 TB
- Set Above 4G Decoding to enabled
- Enabled PCI PERR/SERR Support
- SR-IOV Support to enabled

I'm running on a Supermicro X10SRL-F-O motherboard